# Fetching my Data in the table to Input boxes based on their ID

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, fetch

**Main Goal:** I want to view the whole details of my specific row data in my table into a new form(input text) based on their ID.

Here is my code to fetch my data into table

```
<?php   
 include 'connection.php';  
 $query = "SELECT * FROM appointment WHERE request_status =   2 AND appoint_active = 1";  
 $run = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
 ?>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading">Listing All Services</div>
        <div class="panel-body">

          <table class="tables" id="manageMainteTable" style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Service ID</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width:150px;">Order Date</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Client Name</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Contact</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Client Product</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">No. of Items</th>
                <th style="text-align: center; width:150px;">Due Date</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Service Status</th>
                <th style="text-align: center;">Action</th>
              </tr>
              <?php
              if ($num = mysqli_num_rows($run)>0) {  
                while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
                   echo "
              <tr>
                <td>".$result['appoint_id']."</td>
                <td>".$result['order_date']."</td>
                <td>".$result['customer_name']."</td>
                <td>".$result['customer_contact']."</td>
                <td>".$result['item_type']."</td>
                <td>".$result['quantity']."</td>
                <td>".$result['due_date']."</td>";
                if($result['appoint_status'] == 2 ){
                    echo"<td><label class='label label-success'>Finished</label></td>";
                  } else {
                   echo"<td><label class='label label-danger'>On Going</label</td>";
                 }
                if($result['appoint_status'] == 2 ){
                echo "<td>
                <button class='btn btn-sm btn-info edit_cat' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#addProductModal'> VIEW </button>
                <a href='php_action/finishAppointRemove.php?appoint_id=".$result['appoint_id']."' class='btn btn-sm btn-success edit_cat' id='dltbtn'>Remove</a></td>";
              } else {
                echo "<td>
                 <button class='btn btn-sm btn-info edit_cat' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#addProductModal'>VIEW</button>
                <a href='php_action/finishAppoint.php?appoint_id=".$result['appoint_id']."' class='btn btn-sm btn-success edit_cat' id='fnhbtn'>Finished</a></td>";
              }
              }
            }
            ?>
             </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

So what i want is when i click this button **

**<button class='btn btn-sm btn-info edit_cat' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#addProductModal'> VIEW </button>**

** The corresponding row will fetch its data into input boxes.

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="addProductModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Full Details</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>

  <form class="form-horizontal" id="submitProductForm" action="php_action/updateMainte.php" method="POST"> 
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="add-product-messages"></div>

    <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="appointID">Appoint ID:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="appointID" name="appoint" placeholder="Appoint ID" value="<?php echo $row['appoint_id'];?>" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="customerName">Customer Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="customerName" name="customerName" placeholder="Customer Name" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="contact">Contact Number:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Contact #" required>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="item_type">Item/s Type:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item_type" name="item_type" placeholder="Items" required>
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" name="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" min="1" required>
    </div>
  </div>


   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="due">Due Date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="due" name="due" placeholder=" Due Date" required>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="worker" required>Assinged Worker/s:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9"> 
      <select class="form-control" id="worker" name="worker">
        <option value="">---Select---</option>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT brand_id, brand_name FROM brands WHERE brand_status = 1 AND brand_active = 1";
        $result = $connect->query($sql);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
          echo "<option value='".$row[0]."'>".$row[1]."</option>";
        }
        ?>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="createProductBtn" data-loading-text="Loading..">Update Information</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      </div>

    }
  }
</form>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the visual example of my table.

[image]

And when i click the view button

[image]

So what i want is to automatically fetch the correspoding row of the view button that i just clicked. Im kinda new to coding so im not really sure what i need to do that. Thanks and sorry for convenience.

Comment: Just add appoint_id as attribute in view button and call ajax to get the full details

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a PHP problem, a MySQL problem, or a jQuery problem?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Step 1: Add a appoint_id (i.e. unique id ) to view button using data attribute.

In Your Case `data-appoint='".$result['appoint_id']."'`

```php
   echo "<td>
        <button class='btn btn-sm btn-info edit_cat' data-appoint='".$result['appoint_id']."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#addProductModal'> VIEW </button>";
```

-Step 2:  Add a onclick event listener to view button. In Your Case

```js
    $(".edit_cat").click(function(){
        let service_id=$(this).data('appoint');
        console.log(service_id);
    });
```

- so you can able to access service id in function so add ajax or fetch api to request the source and get data from it. And add Data to desired Input